# Alter response.body in Rack Middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, rack-middleware

I'm trying to write some Rack Middleware for a Rails 4.2 app that alters the response body using the `gsub` method. I found older examples that use a pattern like this:

```
class MyMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
    # do some stuff
    [status, headers, response]
  end
end
```

What I'm finding is that there is no setter method for `response.body`. Is there another pattern I can start with to go about modifying the body?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that it expects an Array for the 3rd argument in the `call` method. This pattern got me working again.

```
# not real code, just a pattern to follow
class MyMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
    new_response = make_new_response(response.body)
    # also must reset the Content-Length header if changing body
    headers['Content-Length'] = new_response.bytesize.to_s
    [status, headers, [new_response]]
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `make_new_response`?

Comment: @AjaxLeung Anything you want. Just an example. Takes a string, returns a string.

Comment: If you use `status, headers, response = @app.call(env)` on the first place, then everything after won't be able to "stop" the request. You skip the middleware stack for your middleware.

Comment: I've updated the code from `new_response.length` to `new_response.bytesize`. The previous code would make the browsers truncate some of the response, as instructed by Content-Length.